# Typescript Getting Child Props in Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am new to Typescript. Let's say I have a component called `TitleSubtitle` which returns both a `Title` component and a `Subtitle` component.

The `Title` component has props:

```
interface TitleProps {
    text: string;
}
```

The `Subtitle` component has props:

```
interface SubtitleProps {
    text: string;
}
```

Now, when setting my props for the `TitleSubtitle` component, **I *could* do this**:

```
interface TitleSubtitleProps {
    titleText: string;
    subtitleText: string;
}
```

**Or, is there some way to do something like this**:

```
interface TitleSubtitleProps {
    title: TitleProps;
    subtitle: SubtitleProps;
}
```

Does this make sense? Thanks!

Comment: *"Or, is there some way to do something like this [...]"* Yeah, you can do that. What's your question?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Oh is that actually how you do it? Is this the recommended way? Also, do I just import `TitleProps` and `SubtitleProps` from their files?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to specify `title` and `subtitle` as specifically of type `TitleProps["text"]` and `SubtitleProps["text"]` respectively, you can do that -

```
interface TitleSubtitleProps {
  title: TitleProps["text"] // SubTitleProps.title: string
  subtitle: SubtitleProps["text"] // SubtitleTitleProps.subtitle: string
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am more looking how to reference the `TitleProps` and `SubtitleProps` in the `TitleSubtitleProps`. Is this good practice?

Comment: Can you clarify in your question what you're trying to type, specifically? Reference those types in what case?